# Handle List of objects passed to django template in jQuery for Ajax call

Tags: jquery, django

I have my views.py function as below:

```
def method(request):
    objects = Model1.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'manager/link.html', {'objects': object})
```

In my template, link.html I have the below code:

```
<script>
        $('#nav').on('click', function (event) {
            $('#stock_holdings').text('Loading...');
            var stocks = ({{ stocks|get_list|safe }});
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '{% url 'broker:load_data' %}',
                data: {
                    'stocks': stocks,
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#stock_holdings').text(data['stocks_details']);
                }
            });
        })
        ;
    </script>
```

where get_list is a custom tag to convert the queryset into a list of objects:

```
@register.filter
def get_list(queryset):
    return list(queryset)
```

However I get the below error when the code is run and I see its due to this in the browser debug window:

**Error:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

**Line causing the error:**

```
var stocks = ([<broker: stock1>, <broker: stock2>]);
```

It looks like the '<' in the list of objects is causing the error. Could someone please help on how to handle this?

Comment: Hi put that inside quote and see. i.e : `'({{ stocks|get_list|safe }})'`

Comment: Thanks Swati but having quotes converts the list of objects to str type and that doesn't help in further processing.

Answer (score 0):

`list(queryset)` would just give you a list of objects of your model. you potentially want a dictionary representation of the model, this might work `list(queryset.values())`
Also it is not recommended to render javascript this way. Try to make a view that would return json and make an ajax call to get that. Also render the urls needed in some html tag as a data-attribute.

Comment: Thanks Abdul Aziz Barkat. The idea is to pass the objects list to the template and make an ajax call to another view method passing this list, this view method would then do the long computation and then return the results. Until that 'loading...' would be shown on the page. If possible could you please point me to some code that could help doing this or some code snippets? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why even pass the objects via ajax? `objects = Model1.objects.all()` you can do this or any other query in the view you are calling and perform any computation you want

Comment: Tried that as well. But now I'm stuck on how to populate the table fields with ajax call and display only the table headings and a loading message until then. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!